# Why is this XSD 1.1 assertion failing?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xerces, xsd-1.1

I am using Xerces-J-bin.2.12.1-xml-schema-1.1.zip package of validating XSD 1.1 resulting into below error.

> example.xml is not valid because  cvc-assertion: Assertion evaluation
> ('count(attribute[string(@distinct) = 'true']) = 1') for element
> 'ts:example' on schema type '#AnonType_example' did not succeed.

Is that the case that it does not support all the XPaths?

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ts:example xmlns:ts="http://tokenscript.org/2020/06/tokenscript">
    <ts:attribute name="building" distinct="false"/>
    <ts:attribute name="state" distinct="true"/>
</ts:example>
```

XSD Code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:ts="http://tokenscript.org/2020/06/tokenscript"
        targetNamespace="http://tokenscript.org/2020/06/tokenscript"
        elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <element name="example">
        <complexType>
            <sequence>
                <element name="attribute" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="ts:attributeWithDistinct"/>
            </sequence>
            <assert test="count(attribute[string(@distinct) = 'true']) = 1"/>
        </complexType>
    </element>
    <complexType name="attributeTS">
        <sequence>
            <element minOccurs="0" name="label" />
            <element minOccurs="0" name="origins" />
        </sequence>
        <attribute name="name" use="required" type="NCName"/>
    </complexType>
    <complexType name="attributeWithDistinct">
        <complexContent>
            <extension base="ts:attributeTS">
                <attribute name="distinct" type="boolean" default="false"/>
            </extension>
        </complexContent>
    </complexType>
</schema>
```

In my Java code I am properly pointing to XSD 1.1 see below Java Code:

```
private static final String W3C_XML_SCHEMA_11_NS_URI = "http://www.w3.org/XML/XMLSchema/v1.1";

private static void validateFile(File xmlFile, File xsdFile) throws SAXException, IOException
{
    // 1. Lookup a factory for the W3C XML Schema language
    //SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
    SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(W3C_XML_SCHEMA_11_NS_URI);
    // 2. Compile the schema.
    File schemaLocation = xsdFile; 
    Schema schema = factory.newSchema(schemaLocation);

    // 3. Get a validator from the schema.
    Validator validator = schema.newValidator();

    // 4. Parse the document you want to check.
    Source source = new StreamSource(xmlFile);

    // 5. Check the document
    try
    {
        validator.validate(source);
        System.out.println(xmlFile.getName() + " is valid.");
    }
    catch (SAXException ex)
    {
        System.out.println(xmlFile.getName() + " is not valid because ");
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Why does your XSD assertion show a `ts` namespace prefix on `attribute` (terrible name for an element, btw) when there are no namespaces or namespace prefixes declared in your XML?  Odd too that the error message seems to be regarding another version of the assertion that `attribute`, not `ts:attribute`.   This does not appear to be a consistent [mcve].

Comment: Thanks @kjhughes for the response. I edited my question and removed the ts: namespace. I am using the namespace altogether but removed here in order to make it simple, but I am aware that there is no issue with the namespace

Comment: I have edited my question adding complete working small example. My expectation is "xml is valid" for above posted xml but it still throwing mentioned quoted error. Can you check and suggest?

Comment: Ok, since you're back to using namespaces, simply put the `ts` namespace prefix back on the `attribute` being asserted:  `count(ts:attribute[string(@distinct) = 'true']) = 1`.

Comment: OMG! extra pair of eyes really helped here Thanks!

Comment: Need to mentioned that explanation below helped me to understand it better. I thought the the error was due to wrong XPath, because I expected ERROR message like: "ts:attribute element having distinct=true not allowed more than once".

Comment: Yes, it would be helpful, but challenging in the general case, for the assertion violations to be reported at a higher level of abstraction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After removing the remnant `ts` namespace prefix, the only other issue in your posted XML/XSD pair is that the XSD references a non-existant type, `attributeWithDistinct`.  Remove that `@type` attribute from `xsd:element`, and filling out full details yields the following XML which is valid against the following XSD, as expected:

### XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<example>
  <attribute name="building" distinct="false"/>
  <attribute name="state" distinct="true"/>
</example>
```

### XSD

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning"
  elementFormDefault="qualified"
  vc:minVersion="1.1"> 
  <xs:element name="example">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="attribute" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:assert test="count(attribute[string(@distinct) = 'true']) = 1"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>  
</xs:schema>
```

If you add a second `attribute` element,

```
  <attribute name="state" distinct="true"/>
```

to the `example` element in the XML,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<example>
  <attribute name="building" distinct="false"/>
  <attribute name="state" distinct="true"/>
  <attribute name="state" distinct="true"/>
</example>
```

then you get the expected assertion failure:

> Assertion evaluation (`'count(attribute[string(@distinct) = 'true']) = 1'`) for element `'example'` on schema type `'#AnonType_example'` did not
> succeed.

as expected.

I have not confirmed your Java code, but the fact that you're getting a normal assertion validation failure rather than a not-allowed error message indicates that you're getting through to XSD 1.1 validation successfully.

---

### Update per OP's change to use namespaces

### XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ts:example xmlns:ts="http://tokenscript.org/2020/06/tokenscript">
  <ts:attribute name="building" distinct="false"/>
  <ts:attribute name="state" distinct="true"/>
</ts:example>
```

### XSD

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:ts="http://tokenscript.org/2020/06/tokenscript"
  targetNamespace="http://tokenscript.org/2020/06/tokenscript"
  xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning"
  elementFormDefault="qualified"
  vc:minVersion="1.1">
  
  <element name="example">
    <complexType>
      <sequence>
        <element name="attribute" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="ts:attributeWithDistinct"/>
      </sequence>
      <assert test="count(ts:attribute[string(@distinct) = 'true']) = 1"/>
    </complexType>
  </element>
  <complexType name="attributeTS">
    <sequence>
      <element minOccurs="0" name="label" />
      <element minOccurs="0" name="origins" />
    </sequence>
    <attribute name="name" use="required" type="NCName"/>
  </complexType>
  <complexType name="attributeWithDistinct">
    <complexContent>
      <extension base="ts:attributeTS">
        <attribute name="distinct" type="boolean" default="false"/>
      </extension>
    </complexContent>
  </complexType>
</schema>
```